# How can I load PNG-Files as ARGB_8888 even if they have no alpha channel?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, format, alpha

I have the following code to load png files:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;
map =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mapid, options);
```

Unfortunately it loads images as RGB_565 if they have no alpha channel. How can I prevent this and consistently load them every time unchanged (no dithering, no conversion, or anything else) ?

If this is not possible then is there maybe another way to load PNG files as ARGB_8888 without BitmapFactory ?

Or is there maybe another format that can be used instead of PNG that also supports an Alpha channel and always delivers ARGB_8888 bitmaps ?

PS: I am using Android 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

I got an idea.

1. Try to load the PNG bitmap without a PreferredConfig.
2. Get the image pixels.
3. Create a new bitmap with the preferred config you want (ARGB_8888).
4. Set the pixels of the PNG bitmap in the new bitmap.

I think it should run.

Comment: And how do you suggest I do step 1? When I load the image its already in the 565 format. What you are suggesting is to just convert it back, but the image is already changed and information lost. If that was acceptable I could have just added a ".copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)".

Comment: You can load an image in the next way `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())` this load automatically the default config of the image.